# Form Submission checks textarea with RegEx

Tags: jquery, regex

I am new to RegEx but I'm trying to make a Jquery call on a form submission to check if a textarea has content and if it does, I want RegEx to check if it contains Alphanumeric characters and spaces only.

This is my code below:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    if($("#ordercomments:contains(/^[0-9a-zA-Z ]*$/)")){
        alert("true");
    }else{
        alert("false");
    };
    return false;
});
```

I must state I've never written RegEx, but after lots of searching i think that, that will look for A-Z 0-9 and a spaces only. But I cant seems to make the page alert the results of the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.test()` for checking:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
  var regex = /^[0-9a-zA-Z ]*$/;
  if(!regex.test($("#ordercomments").val())){
    alert("false");
  }else{
    alert("true");
  };
  return false;
});
```

[**You can check this out in fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ECp7x/)